# How can I get more information from clang substitution-failure errors?

Tags: debugging, c++11, clang, template-meta-programming, eigen3

I have the following `std::begin` wrappers around Eigen3 matrices:

```
namespace std {
template<class T, int nd> auto begin(Eigen::Matrix<T,nd,1>& v)
-> decltype(v.data()) { return v.data(); }
}
```

Substitution fails, and I get a compiler error (***error**: no matching function for call to 'begin'*). For this overload, clang outputs the following:

```
.../file:line:char note: candidate template ignored: 
substitution failure [with T = double, nd = 4]
template<class T, int nd> auto begin(Eigen::Matrix<T,nd,1>& v)
                               ^
```

I want this overload to be selected. I am expecting the types to be `double` and `int`, i.e. they are deduced as I want them to be deduced (and hopefully correctly). By looking at the function, I don't see anything that can actually fail.

Every now and then I get similar errors. Here, clang tells me: **substitution failure**, I'm not putting this function into the overload resolution set. However, this does not help me debugging *at all*. *Why* did substitution failed? What exactly couldn't be substituted where? The only thing obvious to me is that the compiler knows, but it is deliberately not telling me :(

- Is it possible to *force* clang to tell me *what did exactly fail here*?
- This function is trivial and I'm having problems. In more complex functions, I guess things can only get worse. How do you go about debugging these kind of errors?

Answer (score 2):

You can debug substitution failures by doing the substitution yourself into a cut'n'paste of the original template and seeing what errors the compiler spews for the fully specialized code. In this case:

```
namespace std {
auto begin(Eigen::Matrix<double,4,1>& v)
-> decltype(v.data()) {
  typedef double T; // Not necessary in this example,
  const int nd = 4; // but define the parameters in general.
  return v.data();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this has been reported as a [bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13309) in clang. Unfortunately, the clang devs still don't know the best way to fix it. Until then, you can use gcc which will report the backtrace, or you can apply this [patch](https://gist.github.com/pfultz2/8376525) to clang 3.4. The patch is a quick hack that will turn substitution failures into errors.